# Styles and triggers in wpf

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

App.xaml contains the following:

```
<Application x:Class="KiramUI.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Member.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Gold" GlowSize="10"></OuterGlowBitmapEffect>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And the Member.xaml has the following:

```
<TextBox  Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="188" Padding="0" Margin="2" />
<TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox2" Width="183" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

inside a `StackPanel` inside a `Grid`. But it does not change the style when I put mouse over the control. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: @Dave Clemmer: Please stay away from the wpf-prefixed tags, also if are going to suggest edits you could do a little more, like fixing the indentation of code shifted too far to the right...

Comment: @HB will do, and will use styles instead of wpf-styles.  Trying to correct misuse of coding-styles tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are targeting .NET 4, if so this feature was [removed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511638/outerglowbitmapeffect-is-not-rendered-in-wpf4).